# Получен код другой страницы с помощью WebClient в C#

Tags: c#, html, .net

Visual Studio 2008. Windows XP, SP-2.
Написал небольшую программку для чтения кода html страницы, а именно https://www.gismeteo.ru/city/legacy/4392/. Код чтения:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };//обход подлинности сертификата
byte[] response = null;

string str = "";
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) // WebClient class inherits IDisposable
{
    try
    {
        response = client.DownloadData("https://www.gismeteo.ru/city/legacy/4392/");
        str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        Logging("Network error: " + ex.Message + " - ");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Logging(exception.Message + " - ");
    }
}
```

И всё вроде бы нормально было. А вот сегодня заметил(запускаю каждый день утром), что внезапно получил код другой страницы. Полазив по сайту, пришёл к выводу, что прочитался код https://beta.gismeteo.ru/weather-tula-4392/ (не отформатированный код только там обнаружил, не говоря уже о некоторых строках). Изучаю недавно. В результате чего могло такое произойти?

Comment: Возможно, некий косяк на сервере (скажем, переадресация должна была произойти при определённом User-Agent или что-то вроде того, но при этом в условии была ошибка, пропускающая пустой User-Agent).

Comment: @Surfin Bird, есть ли адекватный способ решения этого, кроме как проверять, ту ли страницу прочитали?

Comment: вообще, по-моему, нет, так-то сервер всегда может выдать всё что угодно. Хотя можно попробовать мимикрировать под браузер (в первую очередь скопировав User-Agent), возможно, поможет.

Comment: @Surfin Bird, что интересно, при тестах последующие 5 часов такого не наблюдалось. Но мимкрирование попробую, спасибо, как-то запамятовал этот вариант, хоть и не использовал еще с WebClient, но это мелочь. А не подскажете, какой клиент лучше использовать или роли не сыграет особо?

Comment: вряд ли сыграет, лишь бы не мобильный UA, а то ещё перенаправит куда-нибудь. :)

Comment: @Surfin Bird, хотя даже в примере на msdn для метода DownloadData, никаких заголовков нету, и как я понял в целом, можно работать и без него, так он нужен для получения данных под определенный браузер, если есть необходимость?.

Comment: ну, насколько я понимаю, обычно данные получаются через API, и так как API обычно делают надёжным и обратно совместимым, подобных проблем вообще нет. Но тут-то страница скачивается напрямую, а тут уже разработчики сайта вполне могут учудить и устроить какую-нибудь переадресацию. Зависит она от User-Agent или нет — отдельный вопрос, но если есть хоть минимальный шанс, что зависит (а, по-моему, может быть), то почему бы и не добавить? Так-то, конечно, результат всё равно не будет надёжным по сравнению с решениями с API.

Comment: @Surfin Bird, жаль, но не все сайты предоставляют специальный API для разработчиков, как, скажем, lastfm.

Comment: на всякий случай замечу, что для погоды есть куча отличнейших API. Например, [Yahoo](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22tula,russia%22)%20and%20u=%27c%27).